# Turn off logging in schedule library

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, scheduler

**Objective:** prevent `schedule` from logging every time it runs.

**Background:**

I am using the `logging` and `schedule` libraries in a python project.

My log file contains information about the physical state of a instrument run by a Raspberry Pi, and is updated every 10 seconds.

I use the `schedule` library to schedule that periodic log.

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) is the limited documentation I have found for `schedule`.

**The Problem:**

The `schedule` library logs this statement, every time it runs a job.

```
2016-06-29 09:01:51,022 INFO: Running job every 10 seconds do update_log() (Last run...
```

The function that `schedule` calls is `update_log()`, a function that calculates the variables included in the log I run every ten seconds and logs them (example below).

```
2016-06-29 09:01:51,022 INFO: Dist: 12.3 m Rate: 23.8 cm/s
```

Because `schedule` is producing its own (fairly useless) log line, it makes the logging I am actually trying to do very difficult to read.

**The Goal:**

Prevent `schedule` from logging that first statement.

Comment: What do you think about setting the log level to one higher than INFO (WARNING) and making your logging at the WARNING level?

Comment: Btw, I LOVE the `schedule` module.

Comment: That would solve the problem, but it feels like more of a duck-tape hack than a solution. I also use warning for events that are abnormal, but not so terrible that the stop the process.

Comment: True it is a hacky solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `schedule` module is [exclusively using the logger called `schedule`](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py#L47). You can use the `logging` library to [disable this logger from writing to your main logger](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate).

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('schedule').propagate = False
```

If you don't want `schedule`'s logs at all, you can also disable it by settings its log level above any real log level.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('schedule').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL + 10)
```

If you just want some messages to get through, set the level to a regular `logging` level.

Since python2.7, you can also use a [NullHandler](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler) instead.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('schedule').propagate = False
logging.getLogger('schedule').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

Comment: This works to disable the schedule line in the log, but I get a `No handlers could be found for logger "schedule"` warning once at the start of the program.

Comment: @MichaelMolter I've added a description on how to completely disable `schedule`'s logging as well.

Comment: I wasn't aware of being able to change the priority of individual loggers. I set the level to `logging.CRITICAL`  to remove the warning and still allow critical errors to be logged. Thanks!