# python logging - different level for specific function

Tags: python

i'm trying to reduce the amount of logging that the `napalm` library sends to syslog, but also allow for `info` logs to be sent from other parts of the code. I set up `logging.basicConfig` to be `INFO` but then i'd like the `napalm` function to be `WARNING` and above.

So i have code like this:

```
from napalm import get_network_driver
import logging
import getpass

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="/var/log/myscripts/script.log", level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s")

def napalm(device):
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    username = getpass.getuser()
    driver = get_network_driver("junos")
    router = driver(str(device), username, "", password="", timeout=120)
    router.open()
    return router

router = napalm('myrouter')
config = "hostname foobar"
router.load_merge_candidate(config=config)
show = router.compare_config()
logging.info(show)
```

The issue is the `logging.info` output never makes it to the log file.  If i do `logging.warning(show)` it does, but i'd like this to be `info`. The reason i want the function to be `WARNING` is that it generates so much other logging at the `info` level that is just noise.  So trying to cut down on that.

Comment: Setting the log level is "sticky".  Why not just set back to `INFO` at the end of the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off logging in schedule library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102291/turn-off-logging-in-schedule-library)

Comment: @0x5453 oh, so i could just set `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)` at the end of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `logging.getLogger()` without a parameter you are currently retrieving the root logger, and overriding the level for it also affects all other loggers.
You should instead retrieve the library's logger and override level only for that specific one.

The `napalm` library executes the following in its `__init__.py`:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger("napalm")
```

i.e. the library logger's name is "napalm".
You should thus be able to override the level of that specific logger by putting the following line in your script:

```py
logging.getLogger("napalm").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

---

#### Generic example:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(levelname)s: %(message)s")
A = logging.getLogger("A")
B = logging.getLogger("B")

A.debug("#1 from A gets printed")
B.debug("#1 from B gets printed")

logging.getLogger("A").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

A.debug("#2 from A doesn't get printed")  # because we've increased the level
B.debug("#2 from B gets printed")
```

Output:

```
DEBUG: #1 from A gets printed
DEBUG: #1 from B gets printed
DEBUG: #2 from B gets printed
```

---

#### Edit:

Since this didn't work well for you, it's probably because there's a bunch of various other loggers in this library:

```
$ grep -R 'getLogger' .
napalm/junos/junos.py:log = logging.getLogger(__file__)
napalm/base/helpers.py:logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
napalm/base/clitools/cl_napalm.py:logger = logging.getLogger("napalm")
napalm/base/clitools/cl_napalm_validate.py:logger = logging.getLogger("cl_napalm_validate.py")
napalm/base/clitools/cl_napalm_test.py:logger = logging.getLogger("cl_napalm_test.py")
napalm/base/clitools/cl_napalm_configure.py:logger = logging.getLogger("cl-napalm-config.py")
napalm/__init__.py:logger = logging.getLogger("napalm")
napalm/pyIOSXR/iosxr.py:logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
napalm/iosxr/iosxr.py:logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I would then resort to something like this (*related: [How to list all existing loggers using python.logging module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249304/how-to-list-all-existing-loggers-using-python-logging-module)*):

```py
# increase level for all loggers
for name, logger in logging.root.manager.loggerDict.items():
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

or perhaps it will suffice if you just print the various loggers, identify the most noisy ones, and silence them one by one.

Comment: hmm trying this without luck.. would i need to change what i'm importing from napalm?

Comment: @PhillipCres Can you please add the imports to the question? I'll then try to figure out.

Comment: thanks! i added the imports to the question

Comment: @PhillipCres I've edited the answer, try out the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks!!  Turned out it was a totally different logger causing all the noise.  I was able to set that specific one to WARN using the `logging.root.manager.loggerDict.items()` approach.

Answer (score 3):

A nice trick from the book Effective Python. See if it helps your situation.

```
def napalm(count):
    for x in range(count):
        logger.info('useless log line')

@contextmanager
def debug_logging(level):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    old_level = logger.getEffectiveLevel()
    logger.setLevel(level)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logger.setLevel(old_level)

napalm(5)
with debug_logging(logging.WARNING):
    napalm(5)
napalm(5)
```

Comment: Since the logger level is shared by all threads, wouldn't this be a bad idea in a multithreaded environment? You may end up logging things you don't mean to, or worse, lose logs you were supposed to capture. 

EDIT: 

I see that the behavior is different if you use the root logger (thread unsafe) as opposed to getting a custom logger (seems to be thread safe).