# how to forbid annoying prints of ASPscheduler

Tags: python

how to ignore default ouput of ASPscheduler like this

> 2022-09-14 15:36:43 INFO Job "UCCIEngine.close (trigger: date[2022-09-14 14:36:43 UTC], next run at: 2022-09-14 14:36:43 UTC)" executed successfully
> 2022-09-14 15:37:10 INFO Removed job 10bd1f4c-23b9-4b62-aa9c-e382314ae0d3
> 2022-09-14 15:37:10 INFO Running job "UCCIEngine.close (trigger: date[2022-09-14 14:37:10 UTC], next run at: 2022-09-14 14:37:10 UTC)" (scheduled at 2022-09-14 14:37:10.0045
> 83+00:00)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102291/turn-off-logging-in-schedule-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust your logging configuration to filter out these messages. If you don't need to display any apscheduler logging, you could do:

```py
import logging

logging.getLogger("apscheduler").propagate = False
```